# How to select only two consecutive checkboxes at a time using Javascript

Tags: html

In html, I have four checkboxes 1,2,3,4. I want to select 1 and 2 at a time, when I select 3, 1 should be cleared automatic, When I select 4, 2 should be cleared (now 3 and 4 are selected, 1 and 2 are not), also I should not select 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 4, vice versa, only **consecutive** numbered checkboxes i.e 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, **but not 1 and

**edit-1**

Javascript

```
function callme() {
            var cbcb1 = document.getElementById("cb1");
            var cbcb2 = document.getElementById("cb2");
            var cbcb3 = document.getElementById("cb3");
            var cbcb4 = document.getElementById("cb4");
            if(cbcb1.checked && cbcb2.checked){
                if(cbcb3.checked)
                    cbcb1.checked = false;
                if(cbcb4.checked)
                    cbcb4.checked = false;
            }
            if(cbcb2.checked && cbcb3.checked){
                if(cbcb4.checked)
                    cbcb2.checked = false;
                if(cbcb1.checked)
                    cbcb3.checked = false;
            }
            if(cbcb3.checked && cbcb4.checked){
                if(cbcb2.checked)
                    cbcb4.checked = false;
                if(cbcb1.checked)
                    cbcb1.checked = false;
            }
        }
```

**edit 2:**

cb1 = id of checkbox 1

cb2 = id of checkbox 2

cb3 = id of checkbox 3

cb4 = id of checkbox 4

My Logic: The above javascript code works when selected 1 & 2, if 3 selected, 1 is unchecked, and now if 4 selected, 2 is unchecked. But now if I select 2 (when 3 and 4 are selected), 2 is not selected, I have to uncheck 4, then select 2.

Comment: You can do all that by identifying your checkboxes with IDs, storing them in independent variable and then applying all the rules that you described.

Comment: On StackOverflow, we help with *code* problems. That means you must post the code you have so far, describe what exactly goes wrong, and what is expected instead.

Comment: oh, code, so editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  checks[0].addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.checked){
      checks[2].checked = false;
      checks[3].checked = false;
    }
  });
  checks[1].addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.checked){
      checks[3].checked = false;
    }
  });
  checks[2].addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.checked){
      checks[0].checked = false;
    }
  });
  checks[3].addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.checked){
      checks[0].checked = false;
      checks[1].checked = false;      
    }
  });    
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check1">
<label for="check1">Check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check2">
<label for="check2">Check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check3">
<label for="check3">Check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check4">
<label for="check4">Check 4</label>
```

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/yQJdQW?editors=1010).

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it (using loops). I've came up with one. But, I haven't been able to figure out the last case (1&4)

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');  
  for(let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++){
    if(i <= 1){
      checks[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        if(this.checked){
          checks[i+2].checked = false;
        }
      });
    }
    else if(i >= 2 && i <= 3){
      checks[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        if(this.checked){
          checks[i-2].checked = false;
        }
      });
    }    
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check1">
<label for="check1">Check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check2">
<label for="check2">Check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check3">
<label for="check3">Check 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" id="check4">
<label for="check4">Check 4</label>
```

Comment: oh yes! this is what I wanted, Thanks

Comment: Tip for the first one: you can use the `id`-s as variables, so `checks[0].something` is just the same as `check1.something`. "`id`-d" elements become implicit variables in browser context.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @tevemadar! This is what I like about SO, I learn something new every time :D